# amp-lightbox background image overlay on top

Tags: html, amp-html

Apologies for not being able to add code.

**Issue:** I have an `amp-lightbox` added to a page. While the `amp-lightbox` is triggered, it opens, but the issue is at a specific portion of the page where there is a container consisting of `amp-img` and `amp-fit-text`. when opened on top of it, the container sits on top of `amp-lightbox`. Not sure how to go about it.

The `amp-lightbox` is added to the bottom section while the `amp-img` is added to the top section.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample to reproduce this?

Comment: @SebastianBenz unable to reproduce it, anyhow have resolved the issue by placing the lightbox outside the container which earlier consisted of the button by which flexbox was called and the lightbox code itself.